# ASMX "Page Method" gets NullReferenceException when called from System.Timers.Timer callback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer, oledb, asmx

I have a database call that needs to occur once an hour and have implemented the System.Timers.Timer class to perform the call. The problem is that once the timer finishes and performs its callback (regardless of whether it's 2 minutes or 1 hour) the system refuses to open a database connection citing an object reference not set to an instance of an object error, despite the DB connection method working correctly when the method is first called via the web service or under any of the other site functions that require the DB and have access to it.

**Is my class being garbage collected while the timer is running?**

**Is there a specific setting i'm missing in my IIS config to allow the Timer callback event to open database connections without user specific input?**

**Am i just crazy and have a poor implementation of an automated hourly database call?**

FYI, the site is implemented as a codebehind runtime compile site.

```
Public Shared noticeTimer As Timer

<WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetOpenDegrades()
    Dim dbCon As OleDbConnection = DbConnection()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT XYZ"
    'Init sql command
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, dbCon)
    'Execute query
    Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    'Add query results to list
    If rdr.HasRows Then
        While rdr.Read()
            .........
        End While
    End If
    rdr.Close()
    dbCon.Close()

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    If (noticeTimer Is Nothing) Then
        noticeTimer = New Timer()   
        noticeTimer.Interval = 120000   '2 mins for testing 1 hour for production 
        noticeTimer.enabled = True
        noticeTimer.AutoReset = True
        AddHandler noticeTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf GetOpenDegrades   
    Else
        'Timer Adjustment if required
        ........
    End If
End Function

//db connection helper function
Public Shared Function DbConnection() As OleDbConnection
    Dim path As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("..\db\db.accdb")
    Dim dbCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+ path)
    dbCon.Open()
    Return dbCon
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong Timer class in mind. I'll take another look at this.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology which should not be used for new development. Use WCF or ASP.NET Web API instead.

Comment: See http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/ExposingWebServicesToAJAXTutorial.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with your code:

1. WebMethods should not be `Shared`. In fact, I'm surprised that works at all as a web service operation.
2. In an ASMX web service, just like with an ASP.NET page, `Shared` resources are shared across all users.
3. You should not perform background tasks in a web service. They should be performed in a separate Windows service, which, in this case, can simply make calls to the web service when the timer expires.
4. If you decide to ignore that last advice, at least don't have the callback method be the same as the WebMethod. If you do that, then the WebMethod will be called from two different contexts - once, when an actual web service request is made, and again, when the timeout expires. In the latter case, there will be no request context.
5. Your problem has nothing to do with the fact that you are making database calls. It's simply that your bad code happens to be making database calls. This technique would probably fail no matter *what* you were doing in the web method.
6. Your code creates various objects which implement the `IDisposable` interface. These should be created and used inside of `Using` blocks:

   ```
   Dim sql As String = "SELECT XYZ"
   'Init sql command

   Using dbCon As OleDbConnection = DbConnection()
       Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, dbCon)
       'Execute query
           Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
               'Add query results to list
               If rdr.HasRows Then
                   While rdr.Read()
                       .........
                   End While
               End If
           End Using
       End Using
   End Using
   ' Don't need the Close calls since the end of the Using blocks will do that
   ```

Comment: Admittedly i'm not an asp.net programmer, so my knowledge her eis rather limited. 

If i don't "Share" the webmethods then when i perform an AJAX call from javascript (jquery) without wanting the page to refresh on POST then i receive an error Unknown webmethod. My saving grace is that this is all for an older (10yr) Intranet setup and this particular page is for maintenance purposes with only a single account accessing it.

Comment: Ok, FYI, this is what is known as a "page method". It's a hack to permit the easy use of ASMX services from AJAX. You're right, it's necessary for these things to be `Shared`, but all the rest that I said still holds. In particular, there will be only a single timer instance for all users.

Comment: With regards to what you mention under #5 I've identified that code placed before the database initialization triggers correctly, however the DBConnection method it's self errors only during the timer callback and not during the methods initial call. I'll look into creating a background windows service to manage the timer and trigger the webservice call that way i can have task scheduler launch the service on system restart's automatically. Only problem is having the service always running on the server when no one is logged is, which is new territory to me.

Comment: Running without a logged in user is what a Windows Service is for.